# why fork and exec are kept 2 seperate calls

Tags: unix, process, kernel, fork

I understand the differences between fork, vfork, exec, execv, execp. So pls dont rant about it.
My question is about the design of the unix process creation. Why did the designers think of creating 2 seperate calls ( fork and exec ) instead of keeping it one tight call ( spawn ).
Was good API design a reason so that developers had more control over process creation?
Is it because of performance reason, so that we could delay allocating process table and other kernel structures to the child till either copy-on-write or copy-on-access?

Comment: How would you simulate `fork` using `spawn`?

Comment: cant simulate fork using spawn..its a combination of fork and exec.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be why would you need fork at all?

Answer (score 11):

The main reason is likely that the separation of the `fork()` and `exec()` steps allows arbitrary setup of the child environment to be done using other system calls.  For example, you can:

- Set up an arbitrary set of open file descriptors;
- Alter the signal mask;
- Set the current working directory;
- Set the process group and/or session;
- Set the user, group and supplementary groups;
- Set hard and soft resource limits;

...and many more besides.  If you were to combine these calls into a single `spawn()` call, it would have to have a very complex interface, to be able to encode all of these possible changes to the child's environment - and if you ever added a new setting, the interface would need to be changed.  On the other hand, separate `fork()` and `exec()` steps allow you to use the ordinary system calls (`open()`, `close()`, `dup()`, `fcntl()`, ...) to manipulate the child's environment prior to the `exec()`.  New functionality (eg. `capset()`) is easily supported.

Comment: At Gould, when I was working on Real-Time UNIX, I designed[*] a system call (actually, family thereof) that allowed fork and exec to be combined - i.e. which allowed you to avoid the overhead of first forking, cloning your current process, and then substituting a different process image via exec -- without the kluge vfork.  // Bot unlike POSIX spawn, altho I think a bit more general. // Had to create a concept of a process object, that could be loaded from a file or cloned from the current process (or a different running process).

Comment: But also had to basically take every syscall, and implement a version that could be applied to such a process object.  Which amounted to provided an extra argument "process_object_to_be_affected" to every syscall.  With the default UNIX syscalls being degenerate forms, with "self" as the "process_object_to_be_affected".

Comment: This is doable. Certainly more general, and I think quite useful.  (E.g. Posix spawn was added because many wannabe OSes simply could not do fork efficiently.)  // But it was a lot of work, although arguably only work that would ever need to be done once.  // Anyway, lots of work => cancelled, proposal rejected, after I had done the top few syscalls. // Note [*]: designed = designed, coded up some but not all. Cancelled.

Comment: A final observation: over the years UNIX and Linux have slowly added such a "do syscall on remote process" featue to more and more syscalls. Ptrace, in particular, can do many of these things.  Debuggers need to.

Answer (score 4):

fork and exec do completely different things.

- fork() - *duplicates* a process
- exec() - *replaces* a process

There's plenty of reasons to use one without the other. You can fork off child processes that perform tasks on behalf of your controlling parent app e.g., pretty common in the unix world. And you can e.g. setup the preconditions for some other quirky application and then exec it from your launcher application without ever using fork.

Comment: Or even more common use of plain `exec`, restart your app (for example network daemons do this if they detect new version of their binary and are idle).

Comment: Isn't it true that `spawn` system call could be implemented more efficiently than `fork + exec`? To me it looks like `spawn` would not need copying data segment as fork does.

Comment: @sasha.sochka Today (and in 2014 too) modern systems use Copy-On-Write for `fork`'ed processes.

Answer (score 2):

From the draft book, [xv6 a simple, Unix-like teaching operating system](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2018/xv6/book-rev11.pdf) used in MIT course 6.828:

> Now it should be clear why it is a good idea that fork and exec are separate calls. Because if they are separate, the shell can fork a child, use open, close, dup in the child to change the standard input and output file descriptors, and then exec. No changes to the program being exec-ed (cat in our example) are required. If fork and exec were combined into a single system call, some other (probably more complex) scheme would be required for the shell to redirect standard input and output, or the program itself would have to understand how to redirect I/O.

Basically as caf says below but providing a good reference. Implementing a simple shell would probably make the reasons very clear.

Answer (score 0):

*AFAIK, initially there was only fork(). But performance reasons called for creation of exec() that does not re-create the kernel structures that are going to be immediately overwritten.* <-- **This is wrong.**

There's a performance problem when a process needs co create a child process which is not a copy of itself.  A fork() copies process-related kernel data which are going to be immediately replaced by an exec(). Thus [vfork()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/vfork) was introduced that does not copy excessive kernel data and any process data; after it, a process is expected to call something exec()-like, and the parent is suspended until the child does so. See 'Bugs' section for description of problems with vfork(), though.

Comment: If that is true, how did people start programs without `exec`?

Answer (score -2):

fork() can only be used for creating a child process.Only replication of parent can be done.
While exec() can be used for starting any new process on the system.
I do not see any correlation above two.

Comment: I think the question arises because Windows has no `fork` or `exec`, but only a combination of them (in Unix parlance, `fork` directly followed by `exec`).